# GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider.OnAuthenticated alternative in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth

I used to have the code like this in ASP.NET MVC app (as part of OAuth 2.0 authentication with Google):

```
GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "id",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            // Here I'm extracting Google OAuth token and saving it elsewhere.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },
    Scope = { "email", "openid" }
};
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

Now I'm looking for alternative in .NET Core:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    ClientId = "id",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = { "email", "openid" }
});
```

I couldn't find any way to declare OnAuthenticated handler with the new approach. Provider property is no longer available and there is nothing close to it. Is there any replacement?